# Javascript Background Change Colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background

I am trying to learn Javascript on my own. So I gave myself a task: Create a button and with that button I can change the background colour. This is what I have done so far. I assume I don't need to run it under localhost like how we usually do PHP? I only drag the file to Google Chrome. So far, after clicking, it doesnt change colour at all. I also wonder why. Would be grateful if someone could point out my error

exe1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
        $('body').css('background', '#' + changeColour());
});
});
        function changeColour() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttonClickMe">
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColour">Click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

layout.css

```
button
 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }

body
 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't plain JavaScript.

Comment: Mind pointing out which part of it? I can't really identify/differentiate pure Javascript and jQuery as I am referring tutorials everywhere to make this work. I am still learning hopefully I'll get better next time :)

Comment: To give a simple answer, any line beginning with a dollar symbol is JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to implement the click event in two ways:

**as a HTML attribute**

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeColour">
```

In order for this way to work, you should use `changeColour` as a function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeColour()">
```

**via JS**

```
$('.button').click(function(){ ...
```

This is the wrong selector for `button` (the `.` looks for elements by class name). Instead, use `button`:

```
$('button').click(function(){ ...
```

Either method will work and you only need one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistakes! Really thankful that you have provided different methods to achieve the same thing. I always thought that there is only one way to do this. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.button').click(function () {
                            changeColour();
                        });
 });

function changeColour() {
                var col =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                $('body').css('background', '#' + col);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning javascript don't jump so fast to jQuery, first do it in plain javascript, like this.

**Pure JS**

```
var array = ['black','red','yellow']; //create an array with colors

function changes(){ //create the function
    document.bgColor= array[Math.floor(Math.random()* array.length)]; //change the document. for example
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I am not using pure javascript. I am feeling so mixed up + confused with the difference between the two after my first javascript tutorial.

Comment: jquery is a library to make us live more easy and our javascript code more clean for example `var example = document.getElementById('id').value;` could be reduced to `$('#id').val()` using jQuery but like i say, if you are learning first give a try to plain old javascript and lester you understand the basic jump to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The selector you're using for the click event does not exist. Add a class to the button for it t work.

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="button">Click me</button>
```

**CSS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
        $('body').css('background', '#' + changeColour());
    });
});

function changeColour() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').click(function(){...
```

is referring to a click on a button with the CLASS button.

Simply add `class=""button"` to your button and it would work, though I'd recommend using `id="myId"` and using `$('#myId').click(function(){` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is fine,

You should move the button class `.button` onto the actual button element and remove the `onclick` and then should work.

Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/745ex5zc/

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try...
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6tjtaqy/) https://jsfiddle.net/w6tjtaqy/

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', '#' + changeColour());
  });
});
function changeColour() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
</script>

<style>
button
 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }

body
 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>
<div class="buttonClickMe">
    <button type="button" class="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```